# Spina upgrade to 2.11.0 : DEPRECATION WARNING: theme is stored as a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spina-cms

I just updated the Spina gem, and my spec suite is flooded with this message :

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: theme is stored as a symbol. Please set and save it again using theme= on your Spina::Account model to store it as a string. You can do this from the UI by saving your account preferences.
```

I do have a factory that use the `Spina::Account` model :

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :account, class: Spina::Account do
    name { "My Website" }
    preferences { {theme: "default"} }
  end
end
```

But I can't find change to this file that solves the pb.

Answer (score 0):

I found this commit on the main Spina repo : https://github.com/SpinaCMS/Spina/commit/3845d25e08a24bc3dbd3f4cd40cb1c5df99fac67

so the change needed was :

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :account, class: Spina::Account do
    name { "My Website" }
    preferences { {"theme" => "default"} }
  end
end
```